# Wildfly http-remoting between two installations on one machine fails

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

We have two applications "A" and "B" running in a seperate Wildfly 10. Application "A" calls services in "B" with http-remoting. I use an outbound connection/binding that is configured via jboss-ejb-client.xml. Everything works fine so far, when "A" is installed on a different server than "B". "A" starts, and I see "EJB client outbound connection established" in the server log.

In development stage we have both apps running on a vmware server with a port offset. Now during the start of server A (B is already running) no connection is established, and when application A is called, I got "No EJB receiver available".

I tried a day and did not manage to find what's going wrong, not even with wireshark.

Comment: Have you set two distinct node names on the instances?  `-Djboss.node.name=node0`

Comment: See also this [post from Evgeniy Khyst](http://developer-should-know.tumblr.com/post/76413785033/how-to-set-up-multiple-instances-of-jbosswildfly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do http-remoting between two Wildflys on the same machine you have to set a unique `jboss.node.name` system property.

You can do that by passing an appropriate value for `-Djboss.node.name` system property to the startup script:

```
./standalone.sh -server-config=standalone-full.xml -Djboss.node.name=**unique-nodename**
```

You will find more details on [docs.jboss.org](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance).